# Raspberry Pi Imager Not Recognizing sd card

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, retropie, image

I bought this CanaKit Raspberry Pi 4, and I have been trying to get RetroPie flashed on to this SD Card, but Raspberry Pi Imager is not recognizing the SD Card. The card isn't bad because otherwise the Raspberry Pi wouldn't be able to run in the first place right? I tried this on a Chromebook and the Raspberry Pi itself but neither was able to recognize the card.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 1):

This really is not a Pi issue as the Chromebook does not recognise the card hence the close request but things to check:

- Do you have the read only switch in any adapter set?
- Download SD Card formatter from [here](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/) and use that first
- Try Balena Etcher to write the image
- If you have the OS running then install RetroPi onto it as per these instructions

Unfortunately, to help further a lot more info would have helped:

1. A link to the kit you bought
2. Details on the SD Card
3. Any actual error messages
4. Any steps you have actually tried to fix the errors
5. Clarity over the Pi running - do you mean on the 'faulty' card or on another card

Unfortunately as we are remote it is hard to guess what you have done / seen but the above are places I start with iffy SD cards.

Answer (score 0):

1 use a sd card adapter to usb
2 go on linux settings by going by the settings app
3 open manage usb devices
4 active your usb adapter
5 and now you can go to rpi imager and you sd card will be showed